# Kotlin: How can I reference a method in kDoc using @see?

Tags: kotlin, javadoc, code-documentation, kdoc

I used to reference methods in Java Doc like this:

```
/**
 * @see com.myapp.view.fragment.PlaybackControlFragment#onPlaybackStateChanged
 */
```

I don't know how to reference same method in kotlin?

The part `com.myapp.view.fragment.PlaybackControlFragment` is linked however method name is not clickable and link.

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just change `#` to `.` and it will work correctly.

```
/**
 * @see com.myapp.view.fragment.PlaybackControlFragment.onPlaybackStateChanged
 */
```

Comment: But what about method overloading?

Comment: What do you mean @RomanMitasov? You want to refer to a parent function from the child class?

Comment: Overloading it's when there are several methods with the same name and within the same scope but with different parameters

Comment: Thanks for explaining what overloading means  I'm asking this question because I don't understand how your question relates to my answer?

Comment: How to refer overloaded method in `@see`?

Comment: > Note that KDoc does not have any syntax for resolving overloaded members in links. Since the Kotlin documentation generation tool puts the documentation for all overloads of a function on the same page, identifying a specific overloaded function is not required for the link to work.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html